# page length not showing after adding export option in DataTables Library

Tags: datatable

page length not showing after adding export option in DataTables Library.

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
       lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],     // page length options
buttons: [


{
extend: 'copy',
exportOptions: {
columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
}
},
```

https://nimb.ws/OlUrQ6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bfrtip to lBfrtip**

```
dom: 'lBfrtip', 
       lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],     // page length options
buttons: [


{
extend: 'copy',
exportOptions: {
columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
}
},
```